# Explain the partitions please

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, disk-management

I am new to this.
I want to identify which is the BOSS Linux OS and which is the Windows OS and if I want to keep Windows and remove BOSS, which partitions should I be removing. I am on Windows OS and checked the disk management, I used disk part to find out the type of each partition.

[image: image of diskmanagement]

After checking diskpart types on google this is what I found:
[GUID Partition Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)

- partition 1 - EFI System Partition - (OS)N/A
- partition 2 - 796badd3-6bbf-4d9f-b631-466eb71a4965
- partition 4 - Windows Recovery Environment
- partition 6 - Windows Recovery Environment
- partition 7 - Windows Recovery Environment
- partition 8 - Linux filesystem data
- partition 9 - Linux swap partition

Also, what is partition 2? I couldn't figure it out.
And where is my windows OS filesystem data like Linux, and why is there only windows recovery environment and no windows filesystem data. Should I remove partition 8 and 9? What is Linux swap partition?

Answer (score 1):

> what is partition 2?

It's an OEM partition, ie. something preloaded by computer manufacturer. Googling the GUID reveals that it's probably Dell's diagnostics software.

> where is my windows OS filesystem data

Take a look at your list. Where did partition 3 go?

It's actually at the bottom of the list, labeled `C:`. Windows lists filesystems that don't have a letter assigned first, ie. everything but `C:` in your case.

Compare the list with the diagram below. The `C:` partition is between partitions 2 and 4.

> why is there only windows recovery environment

Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking here.

> Should I remove partition 8 and 9?

Only if you want to nuke your Linux installation.

> What is Linux swap partition?

Have you tried to google it? It's where Linux offloads data to free up RAM for more urgent tasks. Windows calls this "page file" and keeps it in files, rather than on separate partitions (Linux supports this too).

Comment: Thanks for answering. So if I want to delete my Linux the partitions that will get removed are both 8 and 9?

Comment: @Tough_cookie99 Yes, but you should start with removing any traces of Linux from the EFI System Partition (ESP). It's where bootloader files are stored. You most likely have GRUB installed there, which lets you choose an OS on boot.

Answer (score -1):

It is hard in Windows typically to find out what partition is used for a Linux OS. Because Linux uses different kind of filesystems and there are many types too. The most common however is the EXT4 type these days. Swap is used for swap space and this is a separate partition on Linux, in windows the pagefile (swap) is typically located on the c drive.

I would suggest using an app like partition magic for a similar app which does show/translate the partitions/volumes on your disk.

You have to share more information though.

EFI system partition and Windows recovery are usually hidden partitions.

If you know what filesystem and size partition 2 is you may be able to know a bit more.

In any case, be cautious what you're removing and be ready for any kind of recovery methods for windows. In some occasions you can break your bootloader and this may have to be rebuild if you remove another OS. So have at least a Windows installer/recovery ready that you can boot from in case you need to rebuild the boot partition/bootloader of Windows.